# Take values of different columns in the same 1 column table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am working on Ms Sql Server 2008 R2. 
now i want one column which has results of 3 different columns of same table.. 
Let me explain with Figure.

Table: mainTable

```
Id    Column1     Column2     Column3
-------------------------------------
 1    urla        urlb         urlc
 2    urld        urle         urlf
 3    urlg        urlh         urli
```

Now i want one column

Table Name: ResultTable

```
Id    ColumnResult  
-------------
 1    urla 
 2    urlb
 3    urlc
 4    urld
 5    urle
 6    urlf
 7    urlg
 8    urlh
 9    urli
```

Thanks in Advance. 
Sahil Patel

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT
    Id = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ColumnResult),
    Column1
FROM (
    SELECT Id, Column1 AS ColumnResult FROM mainTable UNION ALL
    SELECT Id, Column2 FROM mainTable UNION ALL
    SELECT Id, Column3 FROM mainTable
)t
```

Comment: Hello wewesthemenace Please read question again i edit that question...  Thanks... Column1 to ColumnResult to avoid confusion

Comment: Glad to have been of help! Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it was useful to you. :-)